# How to Prove Immutabiltiy of String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, immutability

In my last c# interview, 
I was asked to prove immutability of C# string,I know what is meant by immutability of c# string,But is it possible to prove immutability of c# string through code ? can i have a sample code snippet please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the object references of both the string objects, they would be same.

Comment: Write a loop that concatenate strings then watch the GC go mad and your application burn through memory like crazy?

Comment: You cannot - in fact you can indeed prove that you *can* mutate a string using unsafe code.  The best you can do is point to the specification that promises that strings are immutable (in the context of CLR safe code).  If your job is programming, you have to get used to trusting the language spec - if the language doesn't do what the spec says, it's a bug for the compiler team to fix.  You can demonstrate an example where the string is not mutated, but it doesn't prove anything.  There may be constructs where this fails.  Until you find one, you have to simply trust the spec.

Comment: Probably they just wanted to listen how you would approach the problem, your thoughts, discussions and so on. Not really expecting you to _prove_ strings are immutable. Otherwise it was just not very good interview question :)

Comment: @J... if you say that then nothing is immutable. because everything inside memory can be changed using a right tool.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes, but this can be done *within the confines of C# itself*.  It's not like we're using a debugger or disassembler or code injection or anything else - just perfectly valid C# code.  If the interviewers wanted a more specific answer they should ask a more coherent and specific question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can prove that a `string` is *not* immutable. All I need to do is to show some code which mutates a `string`, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string test = "ABCDEF"; // Strings are immutable, right?
            char[] chars = new StringToChar {str = test}.chr;
            chars[0] = 'X';

            // On an x32 release or debug build or on an x64 debug build, 
            // the following prints "XBCDEF".
            // On an x64 release build, it prints "ABXDEF".
            // In both cases, we have changed the contents of 'test' without using
            // any 'unsafe' code...

            Console.WriteLine(test);

            // The following line is even more disturbing, since the constant
            // string "ABCDEF" has been mutated too (because the interned 'constant' string was mutated).

            Console.WriteLine("ABCDEF");
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct StringToChar
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public string str;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public char[] chr;
    }
}
```

Now whether this should be considered a bug in C# is a different matter. :)
(The answer is probably that `FieldOffset` should be considered to be `unsafe` - the code above is purportedly `safe` and therefore the `string` should not be mutatable.)

Also, I think you could legitimately argue that `string` is immutable in spirit, even if there are silly edge cases which violate its immutability in supposedly safe code.

Comment: How does this prove that strings are mutable? Isn't this the same concept as something like `stringVariable += "some string";`? When you do that last line of code, the compiler cannot simply concatenate the current value of `stringVariable` and the new string you provided; instead it creates a new string object and sets it equal to the new concatenated string.

Comment: u proved string as mutable object,how does this prove immutability of string,@shamseer k smr answered correct answer

Comment: `FieldOffset` should definitely be `unsafe`, and not just because of this one example.  Excellent example.

Comment: @samurai I think you may need to consider the logic of the situation more carefully.  A string cannot be both immutable and mutable at the same time.  Since the former is a proof of a negative, the latter immediately invalidates any supposed proof thereof.  The answer to the question of "How can you prove c# strings are immutable" is that you *cannot* because they are not immutable.  Just because they are not mutated *in some cases* does not prove that they *cannot be mutated*.

Comment: @samurai Simple logic, if you can directly prove that `string` is mutable by showing a case where it can be mutated, it means that it cannot be immutable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You haven't answered my comment on how this proves strings are mutable. How is this different from the way the compiler treats string concatenation?

Comment: @Sylverac The string referenced by `test` has been altered without assigning to it a new string, therefore it has been mutated. Therefore strings are mutable. What you're missing is that when you concatenate strings, a NEW string is created. My code does not create any new strings.

Comment: @Sylverac Also try the code with my latest edit where I added `Console.WriteLine("ABCDEF");` - which doesn't even print "ABCDEF" any more!

Comment: @MatthewWatson But again, how is this different from how the compiler handles string concatenation?When you concatenate a string, it does not appear like it is creating a new string, but it is behind the scenes. Is your example code not doing the same thing? I know **you**, the developer, are not telling the compiler explicitly to create a new string, but is the compiler doing that when you are telling it to modify the character array (just like it does when concatenating a string)?

Comment: @Sylverac No, it's not the same at all. The compiler isn't creating the new strings directly itself when you concatenate them - it's the implementation of the concatenation methods inside `String` that does that (have a look at the implementation in the [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,17e1cc2f91f20974,references)). These create and return references to new strings. Also note that a `str += "XXX"` string concatenation gets turned into a call to `str = string.Concat(str, "XXX")`. New strings are created for `+=`, but my code does NOT create them.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, my mistake for generalizing and saying it is the compiler that does the new string creation; I realize it is the implementation of `string.Concat`. I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around your code. I get that `new StringToChar { str = test }` creates a new instance of a `StringToChar` struct and initializes the `str` field with the value of `test`. But what does the `.chr` at the end of the statement do? (Thanks for bearing with my ignorance and answering my questions).

Comment: @Sylverac What happens is: Firstly an instance of the `StringToChar` struct is created, with a reference to the string `test` assigned to the struct's `str` field (note: A reference is assigned, not a copy of the string). Then the `chr` field in the struct is used to access the contents of the string as if it was an array of chars (i.e. providing direct access to the string contents). It does this by using `FieldOffset(0)` to make the struct act like a C++ union. Finally the code changes the first element of the char array (which changes the underlying string).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ahh, okay thanks for the explanation. You definitely blew my mind with this answer.

Comment: This is probably one of my all time favorite answers on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to prove immutability of c# string using `ObjectIDGenerator` Class.

> Following answer is taken from CodAffection article on [String Vs Stringbuilder](https://medium.com/@CodAffection/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-54098af9c354) in C#

Actually ObjectIDGenerator will return an unique integer value for instances that we created in our programs.With the help of this class we can check whether new instance is created or not for various operations on string and stringbuilder .Consider following program

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
 
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    ObjectIDGenerator idGenerator = new ObjectIDGenerator();
    bool blStatus = new bool();
    //just ignore this blStatus Now.
    String str = "My first string was ";
    Console.WriteLine("str = {0}", str);
    Console.WriteLine("Instance Id : {0}", idGenerator.GetId(str, out blStatus));
    //here blStatus get True for new instace otherwise it will be false
    Console.WriteLine("this instance is new : {0}\n", blStatus);
    str += "Hello World";
    Console.WriteLine("str = {0}", str);
    Console.WriteLine("Instance Id : {0}", idGenerator.GetId(str, out blStatus));
    Console.WriteLine("this instance is new : {0}\n", blStatus);
    //Now str="My first string was Hello World"
    StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder("My Favourate Programming Font is ");
    Console.WriteLine("sbr = {0}", sbr);
    Console.WriteLine("Instance Id : {0}", idGenerator.GetId(sbr, out blStatus));
    Console.WriteLine("this instance is new : {0}\n", blStatus);
    sbr.Append("Inconsolata");
    Console.WriteLine("sbr = {0}", sbr);
    Console.WriteLine("Instance Id : {0}", idGenerator.GetId(sbr, out blStatus));
    Console.WriteLine("this instance is new : {0}\n", blStatus);
    //Now sbr="My Favourate Programming Font is Inconsolata"
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Output Will look like this
[image]

Instance id for string get changed from 1 to 2 when str concatenated with “Hello World”.while instance id of sbr remains same as 3 after append operation also. This tells all about mutability and immutability. blStatus variable indicate whether the instance is new or not.

You can find complete article [here](https://medium.com/@CodAffection/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-54098af9c354).

Comment: let me check it first, if it is correct i will accept your answer

Comment: This only  proves that the operators and methods you are testing create new string instances. It does not prove that strings are always immutable. See J's comment below the question why it's not possible to prove in a _mathematical/scientific_ meaning of prove.

Comment: ‒1 for the verifably false statement `It is possible to prove immutability of c# string`, will switch to upvote if you edit your answer to remove this assertion and incorporate information provided by @RenéVogt