# Why does using FieldOffset(0) in C# end up with different pointers for char array and string?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, unsafe

As a follow up on the good answer for string immutability (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253663/6619353) I've started experimenting with this technique to understand the offset of the modifiable bytes.

Finally I've discovered that using `[FieldOffset(0)]` for two references fields does not make pointers have the same values.

Here is the test:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct MutableString
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] 
        public readonly string AsString;

        [FieldOffset(0)] 
        public readonly char[] AsCharArray;

        public MutableString(string original)
        {
            AsCharArray = null;
            AsString = original;
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mutableString = new MutableString("test");

            fixed (char* pString = mutableString.AsString, pCharArray = mutableString.AsCharArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((long)pString);    // 2229380919860
                Console.WriteLine((long)pCharArray); // 2229380919864
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above prints different numbers (exact values will differ from time to time of course).

The difference is always 4 bytes (2 chars).

Here is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net47</TargetFrameworks>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Behavior is the same for .NET Core dll and net47 exe, Debug/Release, x86/x64 build configuration.

Host machine is Win10 x64.

I'm wondering how it is possible that after assigning only `AsString` field I'm getting **another** value in the field with the same offset?

Comment: 4 bytes is actually 4 chars.

Comment: @preciousbetine: no, not in C# it's not. Each C# `char` value is 16 bits.

Comment: @preciousbetine C# uses UTF-16 for characters, so one char is 2 bytes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks! I just did `Console.WriteLine(sizeof(char))` and I got a `2`.

Comment: Your stated behavior doesn't reproduce for me. I get the same values in each variable. Note that I'm not using whatever test framework you are using; I just ran it in a straight console program. You should update your code example accordingly, to make sure that your test framework isn't causing the issue.

Comment: You should also make sure you are clear about what environment you're running in. Things like Windows vs Linux, Core vs Desktop, x86 vs x64, all could be relevant.

Comment: @PeterDuniho my bad, updated the question now.

Comment: The kind of union hacks are fundamentally unsafe, even though you don't have to use the `unsafe` keyword.  The attributes are recognized by the CLR, they are not part of the C# language specification.  You get a pointer to the first character in the string, or first element in the array.  What you see that the object layout for String is not the same as for array.  It is specific to 64-bit code, an array uses 4 padding bytes after the first field in the class to get the array content to aligned to 8.  It does so regardless of the array element type.  String doesn't, char doesn't need it.

Comment: @Hans: _"an array uses 4 padding bytes after the first field in the class to get the array content to aligned to 8"_ -- I think it would be clearer/more-precise to explain that the padding doesn't in and of itself align the array content to a multiple of 8, but rather ensures that the object having as a whole been aligned to a multiple of 8, the array content itself _also_ winds up aligned to a multiple of 8. The actual alignment occurs as part of the object allocation; the padding just ensures that the content within the object also is aligned as a result.

Comment: That would not make sense, the object is already aligned to 8.  It is the first field that would misalign the array data if no padding were used.

Comment: @Hans: _"the object is already aligned to 8"_ -- you know that. I know that. But the person reading your explanation would not necessarily know that. _"That would not make sense"_ -- au contraire. It makes perfect sense to explain that the object itself is already aligned to a multiple of 8, and that the padding is there to ensure that within the object, the array is also aligned to a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering how it is possible that after assigning only AsString field I'm getting another value in the field with the same offset?

You're not.

If you compare the two field values with `object.ReferenceEquals(mutableString.AsString, mutableString.AsCharArray)`, you'll find the two fields are equal, just as expected.

What's tripping you up is the implicit conversion from the `string` and `char[]` types to the pointer. Both of those types are managed types, so the `fixed` statement has to pin the objects and return an appropriate pointer to the `char` data. It's this conversion that's going wrong, not the value actually stored in your struct.

As for why the conversion goes wrong, it's due to [padding differences in arrays between 64-bit and 32-bit processes](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/object.h#L565). The difference appears between .NET Framework (desktop) and Core because the default project settings are different: desktop defaults to preferring 32-bit, while Core defaults to not preferring 32-bit (i.e. "Prefer 32-bit" is not checked — indeed, the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox in VS doesn't appear to do anything for Core projects…I had to explicitly set the platform type to x86 to get a 32-bit process for Core).

The implicit conversion from `char[]` to a pointer is expecting the extra 4 bytes of padding. But since your reference is not actually a reference to a `char[]` object, but instead is a reference to a `string` object, that padding isn't actually present and so the pointer winds up 4 bytes too far.

Given that there's really no reason to expect a reference to a `string` object to be valid when reinterpreted as a reference to a `char[]` object — the object layouts are coincidentally compatible in a 32-bit process, but that's not something the .NET spec promises (it's an implementation detail) — I view this as "reasonable". If you want to create what is effectively a union data structure, you have to put into place your own safeguards to make sure that you only ever interpret the union-ed field as the one that you actually set.

Comment: The difference is not "padding". Strings have a 32 bit Length property immediately preceding the actual characters while a char[] has a 64 bit LongLength property (which can also be accessed as a 32 bit Length property) immediately preceding the actual characters. Both Length properties lie on the same 8 byte (64 bit) boundary (thus giving the same apparent value for both) but the character pointers created by `fixed` point to where the characters would begin for the corresponding type, i.e +4 bytes (skip over Length) for the string and +8 bytes (skip over LongLength) for the char[].